# reference cell via two partial matches on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I need to match two conditions on the cell `Name` and add the price information into cell `price` if both condition match. In other words, if `Name` contains both conditions, get the `price`. I tried different approaches using `QUERY, SEARCH; FIND; VLOOKUP` but I got stuck somewhere in the middle. Here's the example sheet (Google Spreadsheet solution preferred over Excel):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zwG3_5Ctg_IZ1kI04Uee-qIvMrNQ4GmEwySmYcMKLfA/edit?usp=sharing

Maybe important: Both, the `Name` values as well as the whole reference table get pulled from other files dynamically. So I don't know anything concerning order or length of these columns in advance, not even if there are matches at all.

Comment: based on your update note, then you need to use my answer, because it doen't take the length of the string into account. it could be anything, ref and names;

Answer (score 1):

Based on your spreadsheet table:
you can try the following formula:
**this formula works in excel not in google spreadsheets**

```
=IFNA(INDEX($G$2:$G$6;MATCH(1;COUNTIFS(A2;"*"&$E$2:$E$100&"*";A2;"*"&$F$2:$F$100&"*");0));"NOT FOUND")
```

this is an array formula, so press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to calculate the formula.
i think it will do the job.

here is [the example file to download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/odr5uute0hvy71h/index%20countif%20partial%20match.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: If I put this formula in e.g. cell `B2` it doesn't work (in Excel, array formula activated)? Did I miss something?

Comment: @ChristianBorck: maybe your excel delimiter is , and not ; as in my answer. here it is =IFNA(INDEX($G$2:$G$6,MATCH(1,COUNTIFS(A2,"*"&$E$2:$E$4&"*",A2,"*"&$F$2:$F$4&"*"),0)),"NOT FOUND")

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't seem to be the problem, my Excel expects `;`

Comment: @ChristianBorck: I added an example file for you, download it and see if it works. By the way, check if your formula options are on automatic calculation in your excel options.

Comment: Thank you, your linked file works, the problem was a local language issue of formular expressions. I updated my example file as well. Now your file is still working for all but cell `B4`.

Comment: @ChristianBorck: actually, because my range was from E2 to E4, and F2 to F4, so I just updated it to E2:E100 and F2:F100, you need to adjust this to fit your range in. I also updated the download file, you can see the changes in the new file.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to previous answer AND given the current set of data (in a Google spreadsheet), in B2 try:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(regexreplace(A2:A; "[^A-Z]"; ""); {E2:E&F2:F\G2:G}; 2; 0)))
```

and see if that works ?

Comment: Nice, this is almost what I was looking for. But If I get this right, you are extracting all Capital Letters in `Name`. Maybe my example is misleading, as I don't know anyting about the structure of text in `Name` column. It will be a mix of lower, upper case, numbers, underscores at least. So the crucial thing is to check if the conditions are contained.

Comment: The formula is built around the matching of capitals. If the names will not have capitals, we need to find something else. Will it be posible that a name solely consists of lower case letter or numbers ? Will the pattern to be matched always be capital letters ?

Comment: If possible, add some more examples (with all the possible 'types' of names) to your example sheet.

Comment: I updated the examples in the spreadsheet. Hope it's more clear now. Thank you!

Comment: Is there some kind of logic that can be used in the regular expression ?

Comment: Unfortunately the only 'logic' would be: Are both conditions strings included in the `Name` column string.